# Keras fit and datagenerator return "Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (None, 1)"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a generator using a dataframe stored in pickle. The targets are 3 columns whith their name starting by "target". The features are stored in the "input" column. Each cell of "input" are np.array. Their dimensions are 51x7 (7 is the number of channels).
(I am trying to just focus on the datagenerator for now)

```
# General Libraries
import os
import math
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy import random

# Tensorflow and Keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, Dense, Dropout, MaxPooling1D, Flatten

# Project Libraries
import config


class DataGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, path_experiment, batch_size, mode='train', validation_ratio=0.1):
        self.path_pickle = os.path.join(path_experiment, 'dataframe.pkl')
        self.dataframe = self.load_dataframe()
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.mode = mode
        self.indexes = None

        if mode == 'validation':
            self.dataframe = self.dataframe[-int(len(self.dataframe) * validation_ratio):].copy()
        else:
            self.dataframe = self.dataframe[:-int(len(self.dataframe) * validation_ratio)].copy()

        self.name_targets = [col for col in self.dataframe if col.startswith('target')]
        self.dataframe[self.name_targets] = np.log(self.dataframe[self.name_targets])

        self.targets = self.dataframe[self.name_targets].values
        self.inputs = self.dataframe['input'].values

    def load_dataframe(self):
        with open(self.path_pickle, 'rb') as f:
            return pickle.load(f)

    def __len__(self):
        return int(math.ceil(len(self.dataframe) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.indexes = range(len(self.dataframe))
        if self.mode == 'train':
            # Shuffles indexes after each epoch if in training mode
            self.indexes = random.sample(self.indexes, k=len(self.indexes))

    def get_batch_labels(self, idx):
        # Fetch a batch of labels
        return self.targets[idx * self.batch_size: (idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

    def get_batch_features(self, idx):
        # Fetch a batch of inputs
        return self.inputs[idx * self.batch_size: (idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.get_batch_features(idx)
        batch_y = self.get_batch_labels(idx)
        # print(batch_x[0].shape)  # Display (51,7)
        # print(batch_x[0].shape)  # Display (3,)
        return batch_x, batch_y


path = os.path.join(config.path_model_input, 'experiment_2', '2')
train_generator = DataGenerator(path, batch_size=32, mode='train')
validation_generator = DataGenerator(path, batch_size=32, mode='validation')

input_shape = (51, 7)
i = Input(shape=input_shape)
x = Flatten()(i)
x = Dense(10, activation='relu')(x)
output = Dense(3, activation='linear')(x)
model = Model(inputs=i, outputs=output)

def RMSE(label, prediction):
    return tf.sqrt(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(label, prediction))

optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=RMSE)
model.fit(train_generator, epochs=100, verbose=1, use_multiprocessing=False, workers=1)
```

When I am trying to run this code I got this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-6dde9c267440> in <module>
      7 optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0001)
      8 model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=RMSE)
----> 9 model.fit(train_generator, epochs=100, verbose=1, use_multiprocessing=False, workers=1)#, validation_data=validation_generator)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    817         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    818         workers=workers,
--> 819         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    820 
    821   def evaluate(self,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    233           max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    234           workers=workers,
--> 235           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    236 
    237       total_samples = _get_total_number_of_samples(training_data_adapter)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in _process_training_inputs(model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, sample_weights, class_weights, steps_per_epoch, validation_split, validation_data, validation_steps, shuffle, distribution_strategy, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    591         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    592         workers=workers,
--> 593         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    594     val_adapter = None
    595     if validation_data:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in _process_inputs(model, mode, x, y, batch_size, epochs, sample_weights, class_weights, shuffle, steps, distribution_strategy, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    704       max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    705       workers=workers,
--> 706       use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    707 
    708   return adapter

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, standardize_function, shuffle, workers, use_multiprocessing, max_queue_size, **kwargs)
    950         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
    951         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
--> 952         **kwargs)
    953 
    954   @staticmethod

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, standardize_function, workers, use_multiprocessing, max_queue_size, **kwargs)
    765 
    766     if standardize_function is not None:
--> 767       dataset = standardize_function(dataset)
    768 
    769     if kwargs.get("shuffle", False) and self.get_size() is not None:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in standardize_function(dataset)
    682           return x, y
    683         return x, y, sample_weights
--> 684       return dataset.map(map_fn, num_parallel_calls=dataset_ops.AUTOTUNE)
    685 
    686   if mode == ModeKeys.PREDICT:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in map(self, map_func, num_parallel_calls)
   1589     else:
   1590       return ParallelMapDataset(
-> 1591           self, map_func, num_parallel_calls, preserve_cardinality=True)
   1592 
   1593   def flat_map(self, map_func):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in __init__(self, input_dataset, map_func, num_parallel_calls, use_inter_op_parallelism, preserve_cardinality, use_legacy_function)
   3924         self._transformation_name(),
   3925         dataset=input_dataset,
-> 3926         use_legacy_function=use_legacy_function)
   3927     self._num_parallel_calls = ops.convert_to_tensor(
   3928         num_parallel_calls, dtype=dtypes.int32, name="num_parallel_calls")

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in __init__(self, func, transformation_name, dataset, input_classes, input_shapes, input_types, input_structure, add_to_graph, use_legacy_function, defun_kwargs)
   3145       with tracking.resource_tracker_scope(resource_tracker):
   3146         # TODO(b/141462134): Switch to using garbage collection.
-> 3147         self._function = wrapper_fn._get_concrete_function_internal()
   3148 
   3149         if add_to_graph:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2393     """Bypasses error checking when getting a graph function."""
   2394     graph_function = self._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(
-> 2395         *args, **kwargs)
   2396     # We're returning this concrete function to someone, and they may keep a
   2397     # reference to the FuncGraph without keeping a reference to the

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2387       args, kwargs = None, None
   2388     with self._lock:
-> 2389       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2390     return graph_function
   2391 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2701 
   2702       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 2703       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2704       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2705       return graph_function, args, kwargs

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2591             arg_names=arg_names,
   2592             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2593             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2594         self._function_attributes,
   2595         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    976                                           converted_func)
    977 
--> 978       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    979 
    980       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in wrapper_fn(*args)
   3138           attributes=defun_kwargs)
   3139       def wrapper_fn(*args):  # pylint: disable=missing-docstring
-> 3140         ret = _wrapper_helper(*args)
   3141         ret = structure.to_tensor_list(self._output_structure, ret)
   3142         return [ops.convert_to_tensor(t) for t in ret]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py in _wrapper_helper(*args)
   3080         nested_args = (nested_args,)
   3081 
-> 3082       ret = autograph.tf_convert(func, ag_ctx)(*nested_args)
   3083       # If `func` returns a list of tensors, `nest.flatten()` and
   3084       # `ops.convert_to_tensor()` would conspire to attempt to stack

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\autograph\impl\api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    235       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    236         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 237           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    238         else:
    239           raise

ValueError: in converted code:

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py:677 map_fn
        batch_size=None)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py:2410 _standardize_tensors
        exception_prefix='input')
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py:573 standardize_input_data
        'with shape ' + str(data_shape))

    ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (None, 1)
```

I passed quite some time on this issue and I can't seem to find the reason of this error, I checked several time all the dimensions of the inputs/outputs and I can't see the mistake that I made.
Any help would be much appreciated !

EDIT:
`print(self.inputs.shape)` and `print(self.targets.shape)` give (1101,) and (1101, 3) respectively.

I tried to do `self.dataframe['input']=self.dataframe['input'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))` before taking the values, but it still return (1101,) instead of (1101,57,3)

I also checked the shape of all the array in the column input:

```
train_generator.dataframe['input_shape']=train_generator.dataframe['input'].apply(lambda x: x.shape)
train_generator.dataframe['input_shape'].unique()
```

It returns : `array([(51, 7)], dtype=object)`
I am not sure If it is normal that it returns "object" as type of the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in this thread: (for the details)

[Convert pandas column of numpy arrays to numpy array of higher dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617760/convert-pandas-column-of-numpy-arrays-to-numpy-array-of-higher-dimension/56620286)

Turns out what I originally wanted to do with dataframe is not quite possible. Instead I used :
`self.inputs = np.stack(self.dataframe['input'].to_numpy())`

Answer (score 0):

There must be some problem from your `dataframe` which means there is some problem in the stored file causing mismatching shape when it is loaded

To verify that is where the problem is, I keep your model creation and fitting code exactly the same, but write a testing generator is also almost the same as your original code except the data is generated on the fly, which correct shape.

```
class DataGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, path_experiment, batch_size, mode='train', validation_ratio=0.1):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.mode = mode
        self.indexes = None

        self.inputs =  np.random.random([batch_size,51,7] )
        self.targets = np.random.random([batch_size,3] )


    def __len__(self):
        return int((51*7) / float(self.batch_size))

    def get_batch_labels(self, idx):
        # Fetch a batch of labels
        return self.targets[idx * self.batch_size: (idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

    def get_batch_features(self, idx):
        # Fetch a batch of inputs
        return self.inputs[idx * self.batch_size: (idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.get_batch_features(idx)
        batch_y = self.get_batch_labels(idx)
        # print(batch_x[0].shape)  # Display (51,7)
        # print(batch_x[0].shape)  # Display (3,)
        return batch_x, batch_y

path=''
train_generator = DataGenerator(path, batch_size=32, mode='train')
validation_generator = DataGenerator(path, batch_size=32, mode='validation')
```

Here I make sure the input is the shape as `[batch, 51,7]`. Run your model creating code and fit, it works

```
Epoch 1/100
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.3640
Epoch 2/100
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 884us/step - loss: 0.3508
Epoch 3/100
11/11 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.3350
```

The problem must be in `self.dataframe['input'].values`. Add `print(self.dataframe['input'].values.shape)` to see what is it

Comment: ```print(self.inputs.shape)``` and ```print(self.targets.shape)``` give (1101,) and (1101, 3) respectively. Do you know how I can fix the shape of the self.inputs ?

Comment: still the problem is in the input, can you print(self.dataframe.columns) and print(len(list(self.dataframe.columns))) ?

Comment: the problem has been solved, I will be able to close it in several hours. If you are interested, you can see the other answer. the dataframe has 34 columns, 3 of which are targets (begin by target)